# Max-flow min-cut existence proof

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, network-flow, directed-graphs

> Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed graph with edge capacities $c: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, $s,t \in V$. Assume there is an edge $(u, v) \in E$ such that it has full capacity in every max $(s,t)$-flow. Then there exists at least one minimum $(s,t)$-cut $(X, V\backslash X)$ in G such that $u \in X$ and $v \in V \backslash X$.

I have been trying to prove this question for hours, using contraposition and a proof by contradiction. I think I'm missing something. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $c_0$ be the minimum capacity of an $(s,t)$-cut, and let $c_1$ be the minimum capacity of an $(s,t)$-cut with $u\in X$ and $v\in V\setminus X$. If $c_1>c_0$ then you can decrease the capacity of $(u,v)$ by $\min(c_1-c_0,c(u,v))>0$ without changing the minimum cut.

Comment: This assumes that edges can't have zero capacity; without that assumption the result would not be true.

Comment: Yes! That must be it, thank you!